# Changing composition layout when dominant speaker changes in Twilio Programmable Video

Tags: twilio

I can't find any documentation about changing the layout of the composition as the dominant speaker changes.  What I would like to do is have the dominant speaker in a larger area of the video than the non-dominant speaker, and that speaker can/will change at some interval.  Is this possible using the Compositions API?

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Instead of the Compositions API which lets you combine each of some resulting tracks into a single file (among other things), I think you may be interested in the [Dominant Speaker API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/detecting-dominant-speaker).

Let me know if this helps at all!